# How do hooks know when to trigger (or not trigger) the body of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Looking at the official [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), an example is given for writing a custom hook, as below:

```
function useFriendStatus(friendID) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  return isOnline;
}

function ChatRecipientPicker() {
  const [recipientID, setRecipientID] = useState(1);
  const isRecipientOnline = useFriendStatus(recipientID);

  return (
    <>
      <Circle color={isRecipientOnline ? 'green' : 'red'} />
      <select
        value={recipientID}
        onChange={e => setRecipientID(Number(e.target.value))}
      >
        {friendList.map(friend => (
          <option key={friend.id} value={friend.id}>
            {friend.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </>
  );
}
```

The part I'm confused about - my understanding is `useEffect(...)` will trigger each time the component re-renders, which as currently described, would only happen when `setRecipientID` is called. But, say another state variable is added, say, `const [nameFilter, setNameFilter] = useState('')`. In this case, the component will re-render every time a user types into the filter, which I think will trigger the "connection" logic in `useEffect`.

I think this would work if `useEffect` took in the `friendID` as the 2nd param, but being new to react I don't want to assume the official docs are not written in a resilient way, which means I'm wrong and the react plumbing somehow knows to not connect each re-render - but how?

Comment: It can indeed accept `friendID` as a param and do what you want it to do https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: Should it though? Based on my understanding, that param *should* be being passed in, but since it's not, is the docs' example just written a bit poorly, perhaps to keep it as simple as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `useEffect` you need to provide a callback that is going to be executed and, optionally, an array of values that will determine when the effect is triggered. Here you have three options:

1. You pass nothing -  `useEffect` is triggered each time components is rendered
2. You pass en empty array - `useEffect` is triggered only once, when component is mounted
3. You pass an array with props and state variables - `useEffect` is triggered when the component is first mounted *and* each time at least one of the variables changes

React does not do anything else to reduce the number of times `useEffect` is called, so yes you do need to explicitly provide variables your effect depends on (`friendID` in your case)